# Invariant measures of Levy S.D.Es

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations, levy-processes

Suppose we call a real valued stochastic process $\{Z_t\}$ to be distributed as ${\cal S}\alpha{\cal S}(\sigma)$ if each of the characteristic functions is $\phi_{Z_t}(u) = \exp\left\{-t\vert \sigma u \vert^{\alpha}\right\}$.  Suppose $\{L_t^\alpha\}$ is a $d-$dimensional symmetric $\alpha-$stable Levy process i.e $\forall i=1,..,d$ we have $[L_t^\alpha]_i \sim {\cal S}\alpha{\cal S}(\sigma \eta^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}} )$ for some constants $\sigma , \eta >0$

For a constant $\lambda >0$, now consider the S.D.E, $dX_t = -\lambda X_t dt + \sigma \eta^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}} dL_t^\alpha$.

- It seems that its true that this S.D.E has an invariant measure which is also ${\cal S}\alpha{\cal S}$.

  Can someone kindly give a reference to a proof of this?
- Is there any general class of functions $f$ for which the above property holds for solutions of the S.D.E, $dX_t = f(X_t) dt + \sigma \eta^{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha}} dL_t^\alpha$ ?